# Ruby: Find exponent of 10

Tags: ruby, math

`x ^ y = z` I have value for `x` and `z`. I want to find out value of `y` using Ruby.

For example:

```
x = 10
z = 100
# 10 ^ 2 => 100
```

My expected result is `2`. Is there any inbuilt method in Ruby language to figure out this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse of exponentiation is called the [*logarithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). In Ruby, the base-10 logarithm (i.e. `x == 10`) is implemented as `Math.log10(z)`:

```
irb(main):005:0> Math.log10(100)
=> 2.0
```

If you need it for different values of `x`, use `Math.log(z, x)`:

```
irb(main):006:0> Math.log(100, 10)
=> 2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

It's logarithmic function:

```
> Math.log(100, 10)
=> 2.0
```